# How to change default pointer size in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, idapython, binary, compilers

so, I'm writing a script to automate analysis, and the code I'm working with is 64bit.

the **pointer size** field shown here is the wrong one:

[image]

I want to change it from within python to 64bit. I've searched the Idapython documentation and previously similar questions and could not find an answer

Comment: That stuff in the compiler options page comes from the `compiler_info_t` structure in the documentation. I'm not sure exactly where you're \_supposed\_ to set it if using IDAPython, but it's part of `idainfo`. So, you can prolly use the `idaapi.inf_*` functions, ctypes with the IDA library to call `setinf` directly, or I think even the "Root Node" netnode iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ali's tip I was able to find the answer

in idapython the following can be used to set the pointer size:

```
ida_ida.inf_set_cc_cm(ida_typeinf.CM_N16_F32)
```

the enum/definition for 'CM_N16_F32' is found in ida.hpp:

https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/group___c_m__ptr.html

https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/structcompiler__info__t.html

and to use it in idapython I looked up the function/module Ali mentioned and found ida_ida.inf_set_cc_cm() / ida_ida.inf_get_cc_cm for setting/getting compiler info specifically for the compiler memory model mentioned in the previous links:

https://hex-rays.com//products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_ida.html#ida_ida.INF_CC_CM
https://hex-rays.com//products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_typeinf.html#ida_typeinf.CM_N64

exciting stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by Ali, this info is stored in the global `inf` structure. It used to be an actual global variable accessible via the `idaapi.cvar` wrapper, but now you need to use the various getters/setters in the [`ida_ida` module](https://hex-rays.com//products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_ida.html).

While you can indeed go down that road and use `inf_get_cc`/`inf_set_cc` or `inf_set_cc_cm`, in case you only need to change the pointers to 64-bit, normally it should be enough to call **`inf_set_64bit(True)`**.

Comment: indeed, thats a better way to do it.